# validate strict with custom exception not working

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a model which has a standard validates method but with the strict option and a custom exception.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :resource,:user,:body,
                presence: true,
                strict: Exceptions::InvalidRequestParams
end
```

exception module is in controller concerns and tests are working fine, so is app. But when I try to access specific comment (say `Comment.find(1)`) through rails console it throws me a

```
NameError for Comment::Exceptions
```

I do know that it is a bad practice calling controller based exception in models but I don't get why tests are passing and raising the wanted error, and app is working just fine but console has issues.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: It seems that also my tests doen't like the validation. I don't get why it is automatically looking for a `Comment::Exceptions` and not a pure `Exceptions` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for the poor description of the problem. It seems that the problem was in rails not loading the lib directory where the `Exceptions` module was placed. I needed to add

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

To my application.rb file